# RunSynchronously may not be called on task that was already started

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am having an issue with a c# class I created for unit testing my application, in particular the issue is around a System.Threading.Tasks.Task object.

I have a list of such objects and on them I want to execute each synchronously.

I call the following:

```
myTask.RunSynchronously();
```

When I do such, I am always getting the following error and I dont know why are how I can fix it.

> System.InvalidOperationException: RunSynchronously may not be called on task that was already started.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you create the task with `TaskFactory.StartNew()`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is that you *started* the task when you call `TaskFactory.StartNew` - I mean, it's even in the name of the method that you are starting the task. `StartNew` creates the task, then calls `Start` on your behalf. =D

If you want, you can either `Wait` on the task, like @Peter Ritchie said, or you can create the task manually like so:

```
var task = new Task(() => { ... });
task.RunSynchronously();
```

Comment: If you have more than one place asynchronously checking if the task is run, `RunSynchronously` has a race condition and will throw and exception sometimes.

Answer (score 43):

It's already started, just use `myTask.Wait()`

Comment: @user2163234 Yes it will, that's what "Synchronously" means in `RunSynchronously` means.  If the task is already started, RunSynchronusly can throw an exception because there's a race condition between the start and the `RunSynchronously` (i.e. the task can complete first, and then exception).  `Wait` simply returns if the task has completed.

Comment: This caused my code to deadlock, Tejs code did not.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to run again a Task or it is in state executed or canceled. Check a part of documentation below:

> **Task.RunSynchronously Method**
>
> Runs the Task synchronously on the current TaskScheduler.
>
> **InvalidOperationException**
> The Task is not in a valid state to be started. It may have already been started, > executed, or canceled, or it may have been created in a manner that doesn't support direct scheduling.

Source: [Docs .NET Task.RunSynchronously Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously?view=net-5.0)